# App Crashes SIGABRT when trying to use Realm

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I am trying to save a simple object with Realm but the app keeps crashing when trying to make a write transaction even when it's wrapped in a Do Catch block.

```
let theme = Theme()
    theme.name = "Custom Theme"
    theme.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    theme.accentColor = accentColor
    theme.numberColor = numColor
    theme.functionColor = funcColor

    // Add to the Realm inside a transaction
    do {
        try Realm().write {
            do {
                try Realm().add(theme, update: true)
            } catch {
                print("Error saving data")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Realm.write error")
    }
```

Here is the object 'Theme'

```
class Theme : Object {
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var backgroundColor = ""
dynamic var accentColor = ""
dynamic var numberColor = ""
dynamic var functionColor = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "name"
}
```

}

Here is a screenshot of the crash
[SIGABRT Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuLA6.png)

EDIT: The code above that causes the crash is only executed when a button is clicked. There is no console output either. I am bringing realm in via CocoaPods.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't really help. Could you share the crash log that comes up in the console? And does the crash happen on launch or only when running the code in the block?

Comment: only when running that code block and nothing in console

Comment: Please share the backtrace and exception message of the crash. The screenshot that you shared contains no relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it might have something to do with the way you're creating the realm instances, try this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

do {
    try realm.write {
        do {
            try realm.add(theme, update: true)
        } catch {
            print("Error saving data")
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Realm.write error")
}
```

Though, usually you won't need to wrap your transactions into a do-catch block:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(theme, update: true)
}
```